# React: passing data from different component to MUI Table Component throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to send a JSON data from a parent component to a predefined MUI table component. but I am getting an error while compiling the code

I have a **tablePane.js** for which I got the code from https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#system-DataTable.js and I have a **mainpage.js** as

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TablePane from '../components/tablePane.js';

export default function MainPage() {

function createData(id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return {
    id,
    name,
    calories,
    fat,
    carbs,
    protein,
  };
}

const rows = [
  createData(1, 'Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData(2, 'Donut', 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
];


    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <br/>
            <div className='rowC'>
                <TablePane MainPageTableRowData={rows} />
            </div>
        </div>
      );
}
```

If I get the **MainPageTableRowData** in TablePane.js file as

```
export default function TablePane({ MainPageTableRowData }) {

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) {
      return order;
    }
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

  const visibleRows = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy)).slice(
        page * rowsPerPage,
        page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage,
      ),
    [order, orderBy, page, rowsPerPage],
  );

}
```

The tablePane.js file already has some inbuilt code as part of MUI tables, and the **visibleRows** function gives me the below error while compiling the code

```
WARNING in [eslint] 
src\components\tablePane.js
  Line 254:5:  React Hook React.useMemo has a missing dependency: 'MainPageTableRowData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

there just a eslint warning, not error. but still has some messy, because the rows variable not exists in visibleRows.

I fixed by some context, you can try it

```
  const visibleRows = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      stableSort(MainPageTableRowData, getComparator(order, orderBy)).slice(
        page * rowsPerPage,
        page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage,
      ),
    [order, orderBy, page, rowsPerPage, MainPageTableRowData],
  );
```